# Weird Segfault in OpenCL

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, opencl

I was working with OpenCl library for quite some time, and it was fine. Eventually when i ran the test programm i encountered such error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 29020.0x38e0]
0x0186e9da in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0186e9da in ?? ()
#1  0x7718b46b in ntdll!LdrRemoveLoadAsDataTable () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#2  0x0186eb00 in ?? ()
#3  0x77140133 in ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#4  0x0086eb00 in ?? ()
#5  0x0186ef60 in ?? ()
```

I'am using the windows 7 x64 system and the x86 amd app sdk version 2.9 with the MinGW. So i'ma linking against libOpenCL.a. Whenever i try to get the number of devices in the system using:

```
result  =  clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &platforms);
```

I get those segfault. Also! Sometimes i get the `SIGI`L fault, `Segmentation fault, illegal instruction`. How can i solve this weird erorrs? Also i cant step into the `clGetPlatformIds` if i type `step` in gdb on the breakpoint which calls those code lines, i immediately get the one or the other segfault. I know that there is a topic about segfault in OpenCL already in this site, but! I re-checked, i'm linking against amd app sdk library, i simply removed it from directory and the gcc printed me `gcc.exe: error: C:/MinGW/lib/libOpenCL.a: No such file or directory` so, i don't know what's wrong.

**UPDATE**

I managed to produce the following output stepping in the `clGetPlatformIds`

```
warning:
STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered


Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x768c025e in KERNEL32!GetProfileStringW () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x768c025e in KERNEL32!GetProfileStringW () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
#1  0x779117b4 in RPCRT4!I_RpcInitHttpImports () from C:\Windows\syswow64\rpcrt4.dll
#2  0x77895dce in RpcExceptionFilter () from C:\Windows\syswow64\rpcrt4.dll
#3  0x77e9b499 in ntdll!LdrRemoveLoadAsDataTable () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#4  0x0194dd08 in ?? ()
#5  0x77e9b46b in ntdll!LdrRemoveLoadAsDataTable () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#6  0x0194dd08 in ?? ()
#7  0x77e50133 in ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#8  0x0094dd08 in ?? ()
#9  0x0194dd58 in ?? ()
#10 0x767e3f5f in msvcrt!_except_handler4_common () from C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
#11 0x767e3ed7 in msvcrt!_except_handler4_common () from C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
#12 0x7612bbf8 in CM_Locate_DevNodeA () from C:\Windows\syswow64\cfgmgr32.dll
#13 0x77e9b499 in ntdll!LdrRemoveLoadAsDataTable () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#14 0x0194e524 in ?? ()
#15 0x77e9b46b in ntdll!LdrRemoveLoadAsDataTable () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#16 0x0194e524 in ?? ()
#17 0x77e50133 in ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#18 0x0094e524 in ?? ()
#19 0x0194e574 in ?? ()
#20 0x767e3f5f in msvcrt!_except_handler4_common () from C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
#21 0x767e3ed7 in msvcrt!_except_handler4_common () from C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
#22 0x7612bbf8 in CM_Locate_DevNodeA () from C:\Windows\syswow64\cfgmgr32.dll
#23 0x77e9b499 in ntdll!LdrRemoveLoadAsDataTable () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#24 0x0194ed40 in ?? ()
#25 0x77e9b46b in ntdll!LdrRemoveLoadAsDataTable () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#26 0x0194ed40 in ?? ()
#27 0x77e50133 in ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#28 0x0094ed40 in ?? ()
#29 0x0194ed90 in ?? ()
#30 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to use the `OpenCL.lib` for vc++ that comes with amd sdk, and it worked fine. I made a test application in the visual studio which calls the `clGetPlatformIDs` and it's working fine opposing to the MinGW. I looked up the loaded modules in the VC version and in the MinGW version. The difference is, the MinGW is loading

```
0x6cbd1000  0x6cbe2d02  Yes (*)     C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
```

And in the visual studio, the OpenCL is loaded from:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OpenCL.dll
```

The MSVC app is build for win32 architecture. So is the VC version, yet the `OpenCL.lib` seems to function differently from MinGW version `libOpenCL.a` of the AMD APP SDK. I tried changing to the 2.9.1 SDK, but the result is same!

**UPDATE 3**

I done a bit of research stepping into the assembler code, with the gdb. After the call to the `clGetPlatformIDs` the programm successuffly executes a few instructions, then the module changes to `C:\Windows\System32\opencl.dll`:

```
=> 0x401a50 <main@4+57>: movl   $0x0,(%esp)
(gdb)
0x00401a57      189             cl_int tN = clGetPlatformIDs(0,NULL,&numPlatforms);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x401a57 <main@4+64>: call   0x402410 <clGetPlatformIDs@12>
(gdb) stepi
0x00402410 in clGetPlatformIDs@12 ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x402410 <clGetPlatformIDs@12>:      jmp    *0x409270
(gdb) nexti
0x6cbd3480 in clGetPlatformIDs () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd3480 <clGetPlatformIDs>:       push   %ebp
(gdb)
```

So i assume there is no linking problems right? I mean, the code is executing in the `OpenCL.dll` everything should be ok. Then the following happens, (i'm using the `nexti` command):

```
0x6cbd3485 in clGetPlatformIDs () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd3485 <clGetPlatformIDs+5>:     call   0x6cbd1030
(gdb)
0x6cbd1030 in ?? () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd1030:  cmpl   $0x0,0x6cbdeda0
(gdb) nexti
0x6cbd1037 in ?? () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd1037:  jne    0x6cbd1043
(gdb) nexti
0x6cbd1039 in ?? () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd1039:  call   0x6cbd3a50 <clWaitForEvents+128>
(gdb) nexti
0x6cbd3a50 in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd3a50 <clWaitForEvents+128>:    push   $0x0
(gdb)
0x6cbd3a52 in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd3a52 <clWaitForEvents+130>:    push   $0x0
(gdb)
0x6cbd3a54 in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd3a54 <clWaitForEvents+132>:    push   $0x6cbd3a70
(gdb)
0x6cbd3a59 in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd3a59 <clWaitForEvents+137>:    push   $0x6cbdeda8
(gdb)
0x6cbd3a5e in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd3a5e <clWaitForEvents+142>:    call   *0x6cbda010
(gdb)
warning:
STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered


Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x768c025e in KERNEL32!GetProfileStringW () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
```

So `clGetPlatformIDs` is calling some Proc, whichi is calling `clWaitForEvents`, then `clWaitForEvents` is calling something at `*0x6cbda010`, that leads to crash. This 'something' at `*0x6cbda010` is a kernel32 function (Here i'm doing `stepi` to look inside the call):

```
0x6cbd3a5e in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x6cbd3a5e <clWaitForEvents+142>:    call   *0x6cbda010
(gdb) stepi
0x7689d5f7 in KERNEL32!InitOnceExecuteOnce () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7689d5f7 <KERNEL32!InitOnceExecuteOnce>:   mov    %edi,%edi
```

If i continue to go further, the trace will look like this

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x6cbd4725 in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
#1  0x77e7c057 in ntdll!LdrEnumerateLoadedModules () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dl
#2  0x6cbdeda8 in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
#3  0x7689d60e in KERNEL32!InitOnceExecuteOnce () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dl
#4  0x6cbd3a64 in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
#5  0x00401a5c in main@4 (some=0x0) at cl.c:189
```

Another trace, (for some reason there is those `??` instead of `clWairForEvents`)

```
#0  0x6cbd1050 in ?? () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
#1  0x77e7c057 in ntdll!LdrEnumerateLoadedModules () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#2  0x6cbdeda8 in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
#3  0x7689d60e in KERNEL32!InitOnceExecuteOnce () from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
#4  0x6cbd3a64 in clWaitForEvents () from C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll
#5  0x00401a5c in main@4 (some=0x0) at cl.c:189
```

The stack trace before the actual crash looks like this. So in the end, why does the `clWaitForEvents` causes crash? I assume the problem is in the `clWaitForEvents` function

Comment: your trying to execute a program the failed in the link step.  since the libOpenCL.a is not in a standard location, the link step needs to have two parameters added (for gcc those parameters would be: '-L/MinGW/lib' and '-lOpenCL'.  remember this: Warnings and Errors need to be fixed.

Comment: @user3629249 i just the have the variavle `OPENCL_LIB='-lOpenCL` in my makefile.am isn't this enought? i assume that mingw just search the libraries first in the C:/MinGW/lib folder

Comment: @user3629249 anyway i did add the `-LC:/MinGW/lib` to my `LDFLAGS` the result is still the same

Comment: For me its clear that your app is not linking properly. I would recommend to use dynamic loading of OpenCL, using for example "CLEW". To avoid all this missing CL/linking problems (and handle all the error from your code).

Comment: @DarkZeros there is no problem with missing cl at the linking time, i just did temporarely removed the `libOpenCL.a` to make sure that applications is linkings against this library, which i took from the amd app sdk

Comment: @DarkZeros i tried using the CLEW and load the `opencl.dll` from SySWOW64 the result is the same!

Comment: I suspect a bug or an incompatibility in the MinGW ABI.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae can this be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with compiling stuff.
It turned out to be a 32bit/64bit address issue.

C:\Windows\system32\OpenCL.dll (32bit)

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OpenCL.dll  (64bit)

Now for the solution.

[Maybe check here: ] http://www.gnustep.org/windows/installer.html